# Browser for Java/Flash playback only

Tags: windows, java, web-browser, flash

#### Background

On the one hand, there are still some very useful websites providing content using Java applets or Flash SWFs. On the other hand, activating the Java and Flash browser plugins pose a security risk, and, for example, re-configuring Java's whitelist each time you encounter a new trustful site is a hassle.

Therefore, I am looking for an **isolated browser environment**, which has only have to package Flash and Java. More functionality is not needed.

**Note:** I do not want to open possibly infected sited. For example, I usually encounter Java applets on old university sites, but do not wish to install the Java plugin in my main browser.

Does such a software exist?

#### Requirements

- Easy to use, there should not be any security prompts — I know what URI I paste into the address bar when I even open that isolated browser.
- Up-to-date with respect to Java and Flash.
- Reasonable price or free.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Chrome

The Google Chrome for years has kept its own copy of Adobe Flash embedded. Using Chrome’s simple built-in updating feature also keeps its copy of Flash up-to-date as well. Chrome is free of cost.

You should remove Flash entirely from your computer for safety. Then install Chrome.

Also I suggest looking in Chrome’s preferences for the setting to only run Flash applets when clicked for your explicit approval.

Comment: Unfortunately, Java is not included in Chrome and recent versions do not even work with the Java NPAPI plugin. Still, this is probably the best solution for Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers like Chrome and Firefox will handle Java and Flash but like you said pose security risks.

The problem is that security vulnerabilities are within Java and Flash themselves and no *secure* browser can make those go away, unless you deactivate plugins respectively.

I don't know what you actually mean by up-to-date because up-to-date browsers only have up-to-date Java and Flash browser plugins. They need a standalone backend software package (Flash Player and Java Runtime) installed on your computer to work, and it is this package that has most vulnerabilities, not your browsers' fault (mostly). You cannot run a browser plugin without having Flash or Java installed first.

Your best bet would be using a virtual system (virtual machine, VM) if you want complete security. Or even having two completely unrelated systems installed on different disks to be safer.

Comment: I clarified my original post. The browser / package is not intended to provide extra security. It is just supposed to be separated from my main browser. Admittedly, I could just install another browser and activate the respective plugins there, but I thought that such a pre-packaged software may already exist.

Comment: @ComFreek You still need to install a runtime package aside from any browser (especially for Java) to your system. This runtime would be accessible to all applications, not only your separate browser.